# Passing parameter with React-Router in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs, react-router

I am learning MeteorJS, React and React-Router and I am having difficulty passing a parameter in the URL through the router. I have searched for the answer and I cannot find what I am doing wrong:

In my Routes.jsx file ('lists' is my MongoDB collection):

```
   render: function() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Navbar}>
            <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/listpages/:listId' component={ListPages} />
          </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

and in my MyLists.jsx file (inside the component):

```
  renderLists() {
      return this.data.lists.map((myList) => {
        return
           <li key={myList._id}>
           <Link to='listpages' params={{ listId: myList._id}}>
              {myList.name}
           </Link>
               </li>;
      });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Lists</h2>
        <AddList />
        <ul>
          {this.renderLists()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When I click on one of the links for ListPages, I get the console error:

```
Warning: Location "listpages" did not match any routes
```

Also, the correct listId is embedded in the line item, but not the URL:

```
<li>
  <Link to="listpages" params={listId: "qksabGvfeuf5PdaJv"} onlyActiveOnIndex=false...>
    <a params={listId: "qksabGvfeuf5PdaJv" className="" style={}...>Inbox</a>
  </Link>
</li>
```

But if I remove the parameter to this:

```
<Route path='/listpages' component={ListPages} />
```

then it works as expected and the contents of ListPages is displayed (right now it's only a heading to see if I get there). So ListPages does exists, but not when I pass the parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that may have stumbled upon this page doing a Google search:

This question may have been asked prior to the current version of React Router, but the correct way to do links with `path='/route/:id'` is to do `<Link to={'/route/' + id}` where the id is the thing you want to display. Since you're missing the key `id` part, you're getting an error.

For example, I want to show a table with a specific ID that I get as a prop.

Routes.jsx:

```
...
<Route path='/DisplayTable/:tableId' component={ Comp } />
...
```

Component I am going to display the table from (SelectTable.jsx):

```
...
<Link to={'/DisplayTable/' + this.props.tables[i]._id} />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your query parameter like this,

```
<Link to={{ pathname: 'listpages', query: { listId: myList._id } }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input. I made the change and the first time it loaded, I clicked the link and received the same error (*Warning: Location "listpages" did not match any routes*). When I refreshed to try it again, now the application crashes on startup with an *unexpected token error* on the line that you suggested.

Comment: As an update, I've given up on React-Router and I've decided to give Flow Router a try...